# Check for right click press Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to add an event listener for the right click so it does something while the right click is pressed. I tried all solutions on google but everyone gives me an error. I ended up with

```
if pygame.event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    print 'check1'
    if pygame.event.button == RIGHT:
        print "check2"
```

Nothing is printed, error:

```
if pygame.event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'type'

Suggested:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #other event types are pygame.QUIT, 
 pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP, ...
    print("check1")
    if event.button==3: #1 is left, 2 is mouse wheel, and 3 is right
        print("check2")
```

Does not work, it doesn't print anything nor execute code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, pygame.event.type [doesn't exist](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) ; can you try [pygame.event.EventType.type](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.EventType) instead ?

Comment: pygame.event.EventType.type and pygame.event.EventType.button, but nothing happening